# ICE candidates gathered only from one network interface

Tags: webrtc, ice

Got very simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pc = new window.RTCPeerConnection();

    pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
        console.log("onicecandidate\n", event);
    }

    pc.onicegatheringstatechange = function(event) {
        console.log("onicegatheringstatechange\n", event);
    }

    dc = pc.createDataChannel("dataChannel");

    errFunc = function(err) {
        console.log("errFunc\n", err);
    }

    successCback = function() {
        console.log("setLocalDescription is a success\n");
    }

    pc.createOffer()
        .then(function(offer) { pc.setLocalDescription(offer)})
        .then(successCback)
        .catch(errFunc);

</script>
```

Got ubuntu running chromium and ***TWO*** local ethernet interfaces.
Running aforementioned code yields only ***1*** call to onicecandidate and 
***1*** call to onicegatheringstatechange. (any STUN/TURN servers are deliberately not specified, so I do expect only local host candidates, but from ***all*** interfaces). Only ***one*** ethernet interface is examined by ICE.

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have permissions for getUserMedia, Chrome will restrict ICE candidates to the interface of the default route. The rationale is explained [in this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-ip-handling-09)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Philipp. Looks like this is a case. But I am a bit lost here - I'am wiling to create a DataChannel-only  peerconnection (hence I do not need a getUserMedia request) AND have candidates from all network interfaces. Is there a feasible way to do this ?

Comment: @psb The short answer is *no* and it will likely become even worse in the future. Join our efforts [here](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-nv-use-cases/issues/1) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1438823) to achieve a dedicated permission request.